# Symfony Validation PHP mappings

Tags: php, symfony

I'm building an `Entity` and trying to validate the data using the **Symfony Validator Component**.

Here's my code:

```
class Data
{
    protected $name;

    public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('name', new Assert\NotBlank());
     }
}

$data = new Data; // Not putting in anything, just leaving things blank.
$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
        ->getValidator();

$errors = $validator->validate($data);
```

Doing a count on `$errors` returns 0, and my code checks that the metadata function get's skipped.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried using annotations to define your validation constraints?

Comment: I was doing that, but the constraints didn't get autoloaded normally and was causing more problems then it was worth.

Comment: That sounds like something else wrong - it is supposed to just work...

Comment: Do you use full stack Symfony2 framework, or just the validator component?

Answer (score 0):

Try registering validator constraints with doctrine annotations first:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

class Data
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    protected $name;
}

AnnotationRegistry::registerAutoloadNamespace("Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint", "vendor/symfony/validator");

$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
    ->enableAnnotationMapping()
    ->getValidator();

$data = new Data();
$errors = $validator->validate($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost, just missing the addMethodMapping()

```
$validator = Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
        ->addMethodMapping('loadValidatorMetadata')
        ->getValidator();
```

I know the question is old, but it was my top search result, so thought I'd provide the answer.